# Let (x+a) be the HCF of $x^2+px+q$ and $x^2+mx+n$. Show that $a=(q-n)/(p-m)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, quadratics, gcd-and-lcm

Let $(x+a)$ be the HCF of $x^2+px+q$ and $x^2+mx+n$. Show that $a=(q-n)/(p-m)$.

Comment: The gcd $x+a$ must divide their difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$x+a$ divides both polynomials. Hence $x=-a$ is a common root for both. Plug in $x=-a$ in both and subtract.